# How to solve this Homogeneous differential equation?

Tags: integration, homogeneous-equation

$$ \frac{4xy}{(x^2-y^2)}\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$ when $y=0 , x=1 $ show that $$ \sqrt{x}.(x^2-5y^2) =1  $$
using this substitute   $ y=vx $.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, solution for this ! with steps :-)

Comment: The rule of the game is: show some effort.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, :-), i made it to following answer, cannot go further !

Comment: Mh, I don't see anything else than the question of your homework.

Comment: actually this not my home work it is for my badge mate which they had math , but i don't :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84138/discussion-between-pl-pathum-and-yves-daoust).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{4vx^2}{(x^2-v^2x^2)}(v'x+v) = 1$$

is

$$\frac{4v}{(1-v^2)}(v'x+v) = 1$$

or

$$v'x =\frac{1-v^2}{4v}-v=\frac{1-5v^2}{4v}$$ which is separable. After logarithmic integration,

$$1-5v^2=Cx^{-5/2}$$

which is

$$1-5\frac{y^2}{x^2}=\frac C{x^2\sqrt x}.$$

Comment: Thanks @YvesDaoust

Comment: @PL_Pathum: this does not appear along the resolution.

Comment: @PL_Pathum: neither, be attentive.

Comment: my bad thanks for pointing  that out

Comment: but i cannot figure out to this $$ 1−5v^2=Cx^−5/2 $$ step ?

Comment: @PL_Pathum: check the other answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84153/discussion-between-pl-pathum-and-yves-daoust).

Answer (score 0):

You have to wirte
$$y'=u'x+u$$
so you will get
$$\frac{4u}{1-u^2}(u'x+u)=1$$
Can you finish?
Simplifying we get
$$u'x=\frac{1-5u^2}{4u}$$
Now write
$$\frac{2}{5}\frac{10u}{1-5u^2}du=\frac{dx}{x}$$ and substitute $$t=1-5u^2$$
then you will get $$\frac{2}{5}\int\frac{10u}{1-5u^2}du=-\frac{2}{5}\ln|5u^2-1|+C$$

Comment: i'll try it and let you know ! @DrSonnhardGraubner

Comment: actually i made it this far but i cannot advance from here, using integration

Comment: thanks @DrSonhardGraubner

Comment: Could you solve your problem completely?

Comment: to solve this i have to get logarithm for both sides then again $2v^2$ remains with log again ?

Comment: you will get $$-\frac{2}{5}\ln|6u^2-1|=\ln|x|+C$$